# Will apple store accept my custom status bar which will show for a moment in iphone?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, appstore-approval

I developing a card swipe reader like application when I connect the device via audiojack in my iphone I want to show a message "**device connected**" in status bar which will be a custom status bar looks similar to original status bar and hide the original status bar. After few seconds it will show back the original status bar. Will apple store allow this or there any issue in it?

Comment: No one here can say with any certainty what Apple will or will not accept. Keep that in mind.

Comment: Yes. MailBox app does it too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use your status bar and hides default status bar apple will not reject. Because you are hiding default status bar(which is accepatable in HIG) and then displaying your custom status bar.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: This may well have changed, but the current HIG explicitly forbids custom status bars (but hiding is ok): https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Bars.html      "Don’t create a custom status bar. Users depend on the consistency of the system-provided status bar. Although you might hide the status bar in your app, it’s not appropriate to create custom UI that takes its place."

Answer (score 4):

Reeder for iPhone does that when syncing feeds. See the first screenshot in [this article](http://www.macworld.com/article/1153202/reeder.html).

So I guess it's ok with Apple.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend when doing so, don't make your custom status bar as exact copy of iOS default status bar. Make some changes in it, like change battery charging icon, change Network Availability indicator etc.